# PPA error while installing Albert application launcher in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I tried those two command and get some error:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/albert`

   ```
   An amazing, desktop environment agnostic, omnilauncher.
   https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/albert
    More info: https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/albert
   Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

   Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
   Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
   Hit:4 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic InRelease               
   Get:5 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
   Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
   Get:7 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
   Get:8 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
   Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
   Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu bionic InRelease
   Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu bionic Release     
     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
   Hit:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
   Reading package lists... Done                                                  
   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
   ```
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install albert`

   ```
   Hit:1 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic InRelease               
   Get:2 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
   Get:3 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
   Get:4 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
   Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
   Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
   Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release               
   Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu bionic InRelease
   Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease
   Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu bionic InRelease
   Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu bionic Release     
     404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
   Reading package lists... Done                                                  
   E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
   N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Albert is my favorite quick launcher, so I have it installed in Ubuntu 18.04. The errors you are getting appear to reflect temporary or perhaps permanent problems with the PPA.

### Installing through PPA

The [User guide of Albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/installing/) refers for more instructions to a [site of openSUSE](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert). There, you click on the Ubuntu icon. You will find instructions there to connect to a PPA that is different than the one you attempted.

### Installing through a .deb installation file

I prefer to install Albert by downloading a .deb installation file. The advantage is that you do not need to add an external PPA. The drawback is that the program will not automatically be updated as new versions appear. Depending on how you see it, this might actually be an advantage. Albert is in strong development, and a new version may sometimes have issues.

The second link on the page, "[Grab binary packages directly](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert)", allows you to download 64 bit or 32 bit .deb installation files.. Right-click the downloaded .deb and select "Open with software installer". This will install the .deb file using Ubuntu software.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some more detailed instructions on how to install `albert` using the [suse repository](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:manuelschneid3r&package=albert).

**Before you begin, you will need to enable the Universe repository**. [Click here for more info](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/167115).

---

There are two ways to install `albert`.

**Method 1 (grab binary packages directly):**

Run the following command to install `gdebi` which will be used to install `albert`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Run the following commands to download and install the 64 bit version of `albert` for 18.04:

```
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/albert_0.16.1_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi albert_0.16.1_amd64.deb
```

**Method 2 (add repository and install manually):**

This method installs a trusted key to your system. [Click here for more info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt).

```
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_manuelschneid3r.gpg > /dev/null
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/manuelschneid3r/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install albert
```

*To install for any other version of Ubuntu, replace the version number `18.04` in the above commands with your version (currently from `16.04` to `22.10`).*

---

Additionally, to delete the repository and the trusted key, run the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:manuelschneid3r.list
sudo apt-key del E192A257
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no package of Albert released in the [`ppa:flexiondotorg/albert`](https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/albert) for 18.04 LTS, but you can download the 17.10 package manually and install it:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/flexiondotorg/albert/ubuntu/pool/main/a/albert/albert_0.11.1-1~ppa1.0_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./albert_0.11.1-1~ppa1.0_amd64.deb
```

Note: I have wrote message to @flexiondotorg to get package for 18.04 LTS in near future.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r please have a look at [the rejection reason of your edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1285971). Thanks!

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r please don't continue to destructively edit posts here. Please come to the [General chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) or [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) to discuss your issue.

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r If you think there is a license violation, a good start would be to link to such a license, so your claim can be validated. However, please come to any of the chat rooms to discuss any issues.