# Albert on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

How do I install Albert on Ubuntu 18.04?

I tried to install it from the terminal following a tutorial for Ubuntu 17.10 but that didn't work for 18.04.

So I purged Albert and want to try again but there is no tutorial targeted for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077685/i-cant-install-albert-application-launcher-in-ubuntu-18-04-please-help helps.

Comment: I read it but found it confusing as am not aware of the terminologies used. Further, I don't know what is PPA, what is .deb files. Can I get simple steps to install it?

Comment: Since you're new to Ubuntu, I suggest you try to limit your initial experience to software available in the standard repositories. As your experience (and knowledge) grows, you'll be more comfortable installing software from other sources. By the way, look at Kupfer which offers a lot of the same functionality provided by Albert and it's just a `sudo apt install kupfer` away!

Comment: here's a comparison of four different of these : https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/5vak0q/ulauncher_synapse_kupfer_albert_which_quick/

although honestly I find the ubuntu start menu gives you this functionality out of the box.

Comment: @tatsu, I saw that link as well but the title doesn't match the comments there!